# cookies/sessions :: best approach for logging a user in & out

Tags: php, session, cookies

When users authenticate with my site, they are issued a session & cookie (encrypted). The cookie contains a boolean value for logged_in.

Currently, when they log out, I destroy the session, which invalidates the cookie and the logged_in boolean becomes useless for me.

Would it be best for me to leave the session and cookie active and manage authentication strictly off the logged_in value or should is it better to destroy the session?

Thanks,
Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dont let the cookie decide whether the user is logged in. Just save User-ID and Session-ID in the cookie and let the server decide whether the session is alive. You can do that by maintaining a list on the server that stores for each Session-ID the last transaction-timestamp and cleaning this list periodically of all Session-IDs that had no transaction within say 1 hour.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am storing sessions in a table, which dictate to the cookie. So I guess its sort of there.